# Stream data from network in AVAudioEngine, is it possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, swift, avaudioengine

I have an app in which I use `AVAudioEngine` for playing files from the local file system by using `AVAudioPlayerNodes` and `AVAudioFiles`. This works perfectly fine.

Now I would like to enable my setup to also support streaming of MP3 files from a server on the internet.

**What I've tried so far**

My hope was that I could create some sort of buffers from `NSURL` objects pointing to network addresses, which I could then use with my `AVAudioPlayerNode`.

I've searched [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=stream+data+from+network+avaudioengine) and the [internet](https://www.google.com/#q=stream+from+network+avaudioengine) in general but haven't found any good tips on how to achieve this.

I know that the `AVAudioEngine` lineup consists of:

- [AVAudioPlayerNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerNode_Class/index.html), which can play audio from an `AVAudioFile` or a `AVAudioBuffer`. I already use `AVAudioFile` for my "local file setup" today.
- [AVAudioFile](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioFile_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVAudioFile), which is to be used for local files. An 'AVAudioFile' is created with an 'NSURL' so I've tried with an URL that points to a MP3 file on a server like so in a Playground:

  ```
  var fileError: NSError? = nil
  let file = AVAudioFile(forReading: someURL, error: &fileError)
  if fileError != nil {
      fileError
  }
  ```

which rewards me with this error:

```
Error Domain=com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio Code=2003334207 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio error 2003334207.)" UserInfo=0x7fbfab424480 {failed call=ExtAudioFileOpenURL((CFURLRef)fileURL, &_extAudioFile)}
```

- [AVAudioPCMBuffer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPCMBuffer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVAudioPCMBuffer), which is the class I was hoping to use, but I can not find any way to instantiate it with data.

**My question (just to make it clear :-))**

Does any of you bright people out there know how to use `AVAudioEngine` for streaming MP3 files from a server on the internet?

Or should I just give up and use `AVPlayer` for this?

Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: *"Or should I just give up and use AVPlayer for this?"* Yes.

Comment: Thanks @TomHarrington. Short and to the point :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's documentation doesn't specify if it can work with a mp3 hosted online but as soon as I try to initialize an `AVAudioFile` with a mp3 url it crashes instantly with a fatal exception. I think that answers your question.

Comment: It does right. Not exactly the answer I was hoping for but thank you for your time and answer.